# How can i read a txt file from a website in python

Tags: python

Im learning NLTk and i need to load in a large file and i dont want to save it on my desktop
How can i read in a file with python thats hosted on a website?

I tried this code here but it didnt work, i assume that the open with is the rson for it but i need to use open with because i need to save it as a file - myfile in this case.

```
import nltk

with open('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt', 'r')as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', 'r')

data2 = data.replace("/", "")

for i, in line in enummerate(data2.split('\n')):
    if i>10:
        break
    print(str(i) + ':\t' + line)
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tut1.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt', 'r')as myfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt'
```

What can i do to use the file in my script without downloading the whole file?

I changed the code to work with requests

```
import nltk
import requests

myfile = requests.get('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt')

data=myfile.read().replace('\n', 'r')
```

but now when i run this i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tut1.py", line 6, in <module>
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', 'r')
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: In python `open()` it works quite different from `file_get_contents()` in php. To perform http request you can use either built-in [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) or [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) (*or dozens of anothe third-party libs*)

Comment: Do not share code in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64947319/edit) your question and add code there.

Comment: no it doesnt, because i dont have image i have text

Comment: Hi, just use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process the first N (here 10) lines of the file, never reading the whole response into memory, here's how to do that:

```
import nltk
import requests

myfile = requests.get('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt', stream=True).raw

for i in range(0, 10):
    line = myfile.readline()
    data = line.decode().replace('\\n', 'r')
    print(data, end="")
```

Result:

> The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation  of
> Atlanta's recent primary election produced "no evidence" that  any
> irregularities took place.   The jury further said in term-end
> presentments that the City Executive Committee, which had over-all
> charge of the election, "deserves the praise and thanks of the  City
> of Atlanta" for the manner in which the election was conducted.
>
> The September-October term jury had been charged by Fulton  Superior
> Court Judge Durwood Pye to investigate reports of possible
> "irregularities" in the hard-fought primary which was won by

The three problems I fixed are:

1. `requests.get()` doesn't return a file-like object.  Add `.raw` to get that, and add `stream=True` to the request as well to get it to act right.
2. You're calling `read()`, which will work once you address #1, but will read in the whole file.  That's not what you want.  I assume you want to read line by line by calling `readline()`.
3. You have to decode the incoming bytes to text before you can operate on them with string methods.  That' what the `decode()` does.

Of course, to process 10 lines instead of 1, you need a loop and a way to do just 10 lines. I added that as well.  I also added a `print()` call so we could all see the results.

I assume that the `replace()` in my code isn't really quite what you want.  I'm guessing that you meant `replace('\\n', '\\r')`, but since I wasn't sure (I don't know what that buys you), I left that to you to deal with. I did fix it so that it didn't completely wipe out the line (not sure why it does that) by adding a second backslash to the search term.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content of that .txt file with no errors like this:

```
import requests

myfile = requests.get('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt')

data = myfile.text
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [`iter_lines()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_lines) which allows you to consume streaming content line by line:

```py
resp = requests.get('http://www.sls.hawaii.edu/bley-vroman/brown.txt', stream=True)
for i, l in enumerate(resp.iter_lines()):
    if i < 10:
        print(l)  # use l.decode() to get string
    else:
        break
resp.close()  # to not hang connection anymore
```

Or even simpler:

```py
for _, l in zip(range(10), resp.iter_lines()):
    print(l)  # use l.decode() to get string
```

Or *the best*:

```py
from itertools import islice

print(*islice(resp.iter_lines(), 10), sep="\n")
```